# iTextSharp: How to add image of PDF as movable element?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Using iTextSharp to add content to a PDF, I'm able to add an image of another PDF by using the following code:

```
    void addImageFromPDF(string inputPath, string imagePath, string outputPath, int pageNumber)
    {
        PdfReader pdfReader_image = new PdfReader(imagePath);
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(inputPath);
        PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create));
        PdfImportedPage page = pdfStamper.GetImportedPage(pdfReader_image, 1);
        pdfStamper.GetOverContent(pageNumber).AddTemplate(page, 100, 100);
        pdfStamper.Close();
    }
```

However, this adds the image PDF as a static element--I can't click once on it to highlight it and then drag it around or delete it, like I can with an annotation.  Is there a way to create a `PdfAnnotation` (or comparably movable graphical element) that has a `PdfImportedPage` as its contents?

Comment: Are you sure that is allowed in the PDF specification?

Comment: @RadLexus, yes.  If you create a custom stamp whose source is a PDF image, you can stamp that image on another PDF, then drag it around.

Comment: @RadLexus Please take a look at this PDF and move around the iText logo: http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/annotations/cmp_stamp_annotation.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at the [stamp_annotation.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/annotations/cmp_stamp_annotation.pdf) document. This document has a stamp annotation with the iText logo. As it's an annotation, it can be moved around by the user who views the document in Adobe Reader (this might not work correctly in other PDF viewers).

The code for this example can be found here: [AddStamp](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/actions-and-annotations/creating-and-adding-annotations#1189-addstamp.java)

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    Image img = Image.getInstance(IMG);
    float w = img.getScaledWidth();
    float h = img.getScaledHeight();
    Rectangle location = new Rectangle(36, 770 - h, 36 + w, 770);
    PdfAnnotation stamp = PdfAnnotation.createStamp(
            stamper.getWriter(), location, null, "ITEXT");                     
    img.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
    PdfContentByte cb = stamper.getOverContent(1);
    PdfAppearance app = cb.createAppearance(w, h);
    app.addImage(img);
    stamp.setAppearance(PdfName.N, app);
    stamp.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT);
    stamper.addAnnotation(stamp, 1);
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

In this sample, we add the stamp annotation to an existing document. If you're creating a document from scratch, you need to replace `stamper.getWriter()` by `writer`, `stamper.getOverContent(1)` by `writer.getDirectContent()` and `stamper.addAnnotation(stamp, 1)` by `writer.addAnnotation(stamp)`.

Comment: is it possible to implement the same in android. Is this code will be helpful?